# Is random forest a kind of spatial feature encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, encoding

From the book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> On the other hand, CNN models have been proved to have much higher
>   modeling capacity, compared to the previous image recognition
>   mainstream pipelines, e.g., HAAR, SIFT, HOG image features followed by
>   spatial feature encoding, `then` random forest or support vector
>   classifiers. Given millions of parameters to fit during model training
>   (much more than previous pipelines), CNN representation empowers and
>   enables computerized image recognition models, with a good possibility
>   to be able to handle more challenging imaging problems. The primary
>   risk is overfitting since model capacity is generally high in deep
>   learning but often very limited datasets are available (that are with
>   good quality of labels to facilitate supervised training). The core
>   topics of this book are represented by examples on how to address this
>   task-critical overfitting issue with deep learning model selection,
>   dataset resampling and balancing, and the proper quantitative
>   evaluation protocols or setups.

[image]

It seems that `then` indicates random forest is a kind of spatial feature encoding. Is this the case?

Comment: RF is a ensamble model, deciding on if or not some "data" belongs to a class based on a lot of decision trees. So the input are just numbers (not images). I guess the meaning here is that images are encoded to numbers (taking care of the spatial dimension, kind of what convolutional layers do in NN) and THEN this data is used in RF.

Comment: P.S. "Introduction to Statistical Learning" has a good intro section to RF. It's good to see what RF actually does. The book is online: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf